# Parse a query string into variable with parse_str()function related issue

Tags: php

I want to get query string from a url and change it to the string format.

I copied the following code from other related posts on stackoverflow, but it is not working properly for me.

```
<?php
 $url="www.example.com/user.php?uname=alan&password=2222";
$parse=parse_str($url);
 echo $uname;
 echo $password;
```

This code returns the second variable **$password** as expected, but it failed for the first variable **$uname**

```
undefined variable: uname
```

Is there something missing in the code?

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You said it yourself: it just parses the query string. That's only the part after the `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `parse_str` does not work quite correctly with your URL. You probably want to use it in conjunction with `parse_url`

eg:

```
$url="www.example.com/user.php?uname=alan&password=2222";
$str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$parse = parse_str($str);
echo $uname;
echo $password;
```

https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php